# jQuery random Background Color not working in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I need some help here.
Checkout this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ydNn6/5/

my Code:

```
$('.start').each(function () {
    var color = (Math.floor(Math.random()  * 256));
                    var hue = 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')';
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', hue);
});
```

I want every div to be in a random greyscale color, however this is not working in Firefox,
works fine in Chrome though. The funny thing is I got inspired to do this from this site:
http://noemi.ro/draw.html
which works fine in Firefox despite having almost the same code.

Any help appreciated, thanks

M

EDIT: What the hell, now it's working, but not in my html, just in the fiddle...

Comment: You probably need to wrap your code with [DOM-Ready-Handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) `$(function(){})`

Comment: doesnt change anything, strangely the code works for firefox in the fiddle but not in my html...

Comment: Please answer questions by answering them, not editing them, and close them by clicking the tick next to an answer not by putting the word "SOLVED" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include jQuery on your JS Fiddle. Add it and it works.

Comment: It works... but just in the fiddle, not in my html :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess there´s just an order problem...just a guess

1. Include jquery
2. Include your script at the bottom of your page in $(document).ready(function(){})
3. Should work as expected.